# How to implement CMMI in any organization?

Tags: development-process

I need to learn about CMMI process. Like what it is, how it can be effective to make process smooth and mainly, how can we implement this in an organization?

I need to know from the very beginning to the end step by step. If any one knows any good source, it will be easiest for me to starting learning. Otherwise, I have to visit and search on google.

Comment: I think the correct procedure is to first search on Google and come here when you didn't find anything. Voting to close.

Comment: Many books were written about this issue. Go read some.